# Menu in java will not call functions switch()

Tags: java, switch-statement

All my methods work fine when being called singely.

I have two menus one `Main` and for the `Customer`.

```
public void getMainMenuChoice() {
    Scanner kb =new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean check =  true;

    while(check) {
        Menu.mainMenu();

        int choice = kb.nextInt(); 

        switch(choice) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
                check = false;
                break;
            case 1:
                getCustomerMenuChoice();
            case 2:
                Menu.mainMenu();
        }
    }


}

//Employee Choice from the Menu 
public  void getCustomerMenuChoice() {
    Scanner kb =new Scanner(System.in); 
    Menu.customerMenu();

    int choice = kb.nextInt(); 

    switch(choice) {
        case 0:
            Menu.mainMenu();
        case 1:
            customerWithdraw();
        case 2:
            System.out.println("In progress");
        case 3:
            createCustomerAccount();
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Enter Customer Passport");
            String passportNumber = kb.nextLine();
            findCustomer(passportNumber);
            System.out.println("Waiting");

     }


    }
```

In main when I call the *getMainMenuChoice()* I can select the customer menu

When I am in this menu and for example call 4 *findCustomer()* It just reloads the the mainMenu and prints `waiting` at the top while prompting me to enter the passport number.

This is a run through of what happens

> Enter:
>
> 1. Customer Menu
> 2. Employee Menu
> 3. Quit Application.
>
> Selection -> 1
>
> Enter:
>
> 1. Customer Withdraw
> 2. Customer Deposit
> 3. Create Account
> 4. Delete Customer
> 5. Find Customer
> 6. Display All Customers
> 7. Back
>
> Selection -> 4
>
> Enter Customer Passport
>
> //It just ignores the method and prints the menu below as well Enter
>   Customer Passport
>
> Enter:
>
> 1. Customer Menu
> 2. Employee Menu
> 3. Quit Application.

Selection ->

```
//Finding a customer
public Customer findCustomer(String passportNumber) {

    for(Customer currentCustomer : listCustomer)

        if(currentCustomer.getPassportNumber().equals(passportNumber)) {
            System.out.println("Customer Found: " + currentCustomer);
            return currentCustomer;
        }

        return null;
}
```

I am not sure why this happens I have been trying to debug for a few hours now.

Is it something to do with the while loop in the *getMainMenuChoice()*?

Comment: When you run this with a debugger, what is the *first* thing it does incorrectly?

Comment: Switch cases will fall through without a ```break``` statement. That means it will execute the correct case but also all cases afterwards.

Comment: @ScottHunter:  I have updates with the full log of what happens.

Comment: @MichaelBiaconi: I have put a break after every case, but the same result occurs???

Comment: I have discovered that when i call kb.next() it waits but the function is not being called?

Comment: Where do you call `kb.next()`?  I see calls to `kb.nextInt()`, but don't those require that you type something?

Comment: You are using `scanner.nextInt()` and `scanner.nextLine()` together, which leads to problems - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/5646962 for an explanation.

Comment: Yeah sorry I put that in just now, Ill update the getCustomerMenuChoic() now. This was just to see what was happening so it waits for me to push a key and then just loads the getMainMenuChoice(). It looks like it is just ignoring the function findCustomer()?

Comment: No, if you use `scanner.nextInt()` followed by `scanner.nextLine()` and type "4" followed by the enter key, then `scanner.nextInt()` will read the number "4" and `scanner.nextLine()` will read the remainder of that line - an empty string.

Comment: You need to put in breaks after each block in the switch statements.

Comment: @ Thomas Kläger: Thanks for the link perfect sorted it out it was to do with using the same scanner object twice